# Angular UI Grid onRegisterApi method call twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Here in my code if I run this independently it works fine, but after integrate in my project the "onRegisterApi" method call twice. It seems some conflict with existing Ui-Grid.

Can Anyone have any idea? How to debug this and find the root cause. I already spend so much time on this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

var paginationOptions = {
pageNumber: 1,
pageSize: 25,
sort: null
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
paginationPageSize: 25,
useExternalPagination: true,
useExternalSorting: true,
columnDefs: [
  { name: 'name' },
  { name: 'gender', enableSorting: false },
  { name: 'company', enableSorting: false }
],
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function(grid, sortColumns) {
    if (sortColumns.length == 0) {
      paginationOptions.sort = null;
    } else {
      paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
    }
    getPage();
  });
  gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
    paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
    paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
    getPage();
  });
  }
   };

 var getPage = function() {
  // server call
};

 getPage();
 }
  ]);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you please take a look of my problem

Comment: Finally I fixed it..... The issue is because of Ui-grid load twice,

Comment: The issue is because of I have using ui-view="home" twice..